# Tap to top in angular

Tags: angular

I have a problem, where tap to top is not working. That means button is not showing up while scrolling down.

My code is below

Html

```
<div class="tap-top top-cls" (click)="tapToTop()" 
    [ngStyle]="{ 'display': show ? 'block' : 'none' }">
    <div>
      <i class="fa fa-angle-double-up"></i>
    </div>
</div>
```

ts content

```
import { Component, OnInit, HostListener } from '@angular/core';
import { ViewportScroller } from '@angular/common';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-tap-to-top',
  templateUrl: './tap-to-top.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./tap-to-top.component.scss']
})
export class TapToTopComponent implements OnInit {
  public show = true;
  public scrollNumber = 100;

  constructor(private viewScroller: ViewportScroller) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
 
  }
  

  // @HostListener Decorator
  @HostListener("window:scroll", [])
  onWindowScroll() {
    let number = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop || document.body.scrollTop || 0;
    if (number > 600) { 
      this.show = true;
    } else {
      this.show = false;
    }
  }

  tapToTop() {
    this.viewScroller.scrollToPosition([0, 0]);
  }
}
```

Not sure what is going wrong as the button is not showing up and could not able to scroll to the top.

Kindly help

Thanks

Comment: can you log the value of ´number´ while you scroll and post the output?

Comment: make sure you are using a valid Icon. The code works fine on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ahjnmt?file=src/app/hello.component.ts)

Comment: **side note** you could shorten your if/else to one line: `this.show = number > 600`

Comment: @katzenhut I have included console.log, but nothing is present in the console. Probably windowscroll is not triggering.

Comment: your code looks fine, and it works in the stackblitz. What css are you using for the classes `tap-top top-cls fa fa-angle-double-up` ?

Comment: @katzenhut the css is just to show double up with some background color. The button showing because i have defaulted the show to true. However by pressing the button doesn't take it to the top of the page. even windowscroll doesn't output in console, though having console.log inside.